# Does MySQL compound Index require to cover select columns as well as where columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Lets assume that I have table A with columns `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5.`

And lets assume that I have a compound index (a2,a3,a4) and PK index (a1)

Which of these queries will use index.

```
 1. SELECT * FROM A WHERE a2 = 'val1' AND a3 = 'val2';
 2. SELECT a1, a2, a3, a4 FROM A WHERE a2 = 'val1' AND a3 = 'val2';
 3. SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.b1 = A.a1 WHERE a2 = 'val1' AND a3 = 'val2';
 4. SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.b1 = A.a1 AND a2 = 'val1' AND a3 = 'val2';
 5. SELECT a5 FROM A WHERE a2 = 'val1' AND a3 = 'val2' AND a4 = 'val3';
```

If any of the queries above don't use an index, can there anything be done so that it would?
Does the index have to cover the SELECT columns for it to be used or is WHERE part enough? For the last question I seem to find different opinions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this summarizes the index usage, based on what you have provided:

1. Will use compound index and look up data in the data pages
2. Will use compound index only
3. Depends on query plan, but likely to use compound index and look up data in the data pages
4. Same as (3)
5. Will use compound index and look up data in the data pages

They should all use the index.  If you want a full covering index for these queries (so there is no additional step to look up data in the data pages), then add `a5` and `a1` to the compound index (at the end).

Note:  MySQL does make some optimizations on index usage.  The above are assuming "normal" conditions.  If the data fits on one data page, for instance, then MySQL may decide that a full table scan is appropriate.

MySQL has good [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on the use of composite indexes (the more customary terminology for what you are calling a compound index).

Comment: 2. this one should use index (a2,a3,a4) and still access data pages, since a1 is requested in select. 
3. Correct, but is there a way to get around this (no lookup data pages). I have tried both with join and a subquery, in both cases execution plan seems quite the same. I cant seem to optimize the table away. Is this because of the JOIN operator?